# Dynamically creation of labels using jQuery and HTML and accessing their text value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a label at run time using jQuery. The code is :

```
var value="Hello";
$("#ID_listOfTopics").append('<label id="ID_item">' + value + '</label><br /><hr />');
```

Now I don't know how to access the text value of this particular label created at run time.

Comment: use `$('#ID_item').text()`

Answer (score 2):

You can access to it normally using id selector `#ID_item` like following :

```
$("#ID_item").text();
```

For the click you have ro use `on()` when you want to deal with fresh DOM added by javascript.

---

```js
var value="Hello";
$("#ID_listOfTopics").append('<label id="ID_item">' + value + '</label><br /><hr />');


$("#ID_listOfTopics").on('click','#ID_item', function(){ 
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ID_listOfTopics"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works fine, but I wanna alert the text value on click of that label.       var value="Hello";
$("#ID_listOfTopics").append('<label id="ID_item">' + value + '</label><br /><hr />');
$("#ID_item").click({ alert(this.text())});                                                            I tried this code, but it didn't work.